# In Django Can i call a view function of App1 from url.py of App2?

Tags: python, django

App1: url.py, view.py
App2: url.py view.py

Can i call a view function of App1 from url.py of App2 ?

Comment: Yes, why not? As long as you import it.

Comment: Yes you can ! What is the issue ?

Comment: yes but why would you do that, bring that view function to the app where the url is. Also why two urls for same thing. But still if you want to do that don't call that view function in another app, redirect that app2 url to the url of app1 which uses that view function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, say that the views look like:

```
# app1/views.py

def view1(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

and

```
# app2/views.py

def view2(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

You can redirect to both views in the `urls.py` of an app, as long as you import it correctly:

```
# app1/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from app1.views import view1
from app2.views import view2

urlpatterns = [
    path('view1', view1),
    path('view2', view2),
]
```

So the app itself is not important, given you import the view function properly of course.

That being said, it is a bit *uncommon* to see this pattern. It is not impossible, and every now and then you see this. But typically the idea is that apps are not that much related. Sure some relations exist, but typically you aim to minimize this.